# Datatable client-side data change/redraw

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, client-side

I set up a datatables that initially gets from server some data and represents it, but then everything is left to the client. Some options are:

```
serverSide: false,
sAjaxSource: mySource,
```

My $.fn.DataTable.version is 1.10.2.

Then I need to change, client-side, the aaData under the table because some working on data is performed. I need to update the DT to show the client-altered temporary data without send another request to server (for two reason: prevent useless traffic and because that data is being altered).
I am looking for a way to edit the underlying DT databean to edit it, so then calling again

```
myTable.draw();
```

on my table I obtain a refresh realtime without sending another get to the server.

The question is, can I access DT data array, and can I edit it?

How is it done if is possible?

EDIT: I need to feed the table the full bean array as it initially took from the server, same format. So individual row/cell add/edit and client-side building functions are not suitable in my case, unless I manually cicle all objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use the code below:

```
// Retrieve data
var data = table.ajax.json();

// Modify data
$.each(data.data, function(){
   this[0] = 'John Smith';
});

// Clear table
table.clear();

// Add updated data
table.rows.add(data.data);

// Redraw table
table.draw();
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7xov3eo/1/) for code and demonstration.